# c++11 functor within thread puzzle

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, functor

Please consider the following code snippet. Using GCC 4.6.1, `x` becomes `0` and `y` becomes `1`.

Why do I get different results with and without using a separate thread? How should I modify the code so that both versions yield the same result (i.e. the integer value is incremented by 1?)

Thanks.

```
struct functor{
    void operator()(int & x){
        ++x;
    }    
};

void tfunc(functor & f, int & x){
    f(x);
}

int main(){
    functor f;
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    std::thread t = std::thread(tfunc, f, x);
    t.join();
    std::cout << "with thread " << x << std::endl;    
    f(y);
    std::cout << "without thread " << y << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Try making `x` volatile. It is legal for the compiler to fetch its value after `std::thread` is created but before `join` returns.

Comment: @spraff: `volatile` is not a replacement for proper synchronization (and this is not a synchronization issue to begin with).

Comment: UPDATE. It works if `int *` is passed to `tfunc` instead of `int &`. Tres bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to see what's going on. Just replace `int` with a noncopyable type (one with a private copy constructor) and the compiler will pinpoint you the exact place where `libstdc++` tries to copy the argument instead of using the reference. In my case it's line 138 in the `<tuple>` standard header.

Whether or not this is correct implementation of the standard, I cannot tell at the moment.

**UPDATE** The standard says that each argument of `std::thread::thread` should satisfy the `MoveConstructible` requirement, and that the actual arguments that passed to the thread function are move-constructed from `std::thread::thread` arguments. This means that

1. the thread function gets copies of the arguments, and
2. the originals may well be destroyed in process.

So passing stuff by reference won't work.

Comment: In that case, I guess the fix is for `std::thread`'s implementation to add overloads to wrap reference arguments in `std::ref`, right?

Comment: @spraff: no need for a fix -- std::thread already handles std::ref.  If you change the program to `std::thread t = std::thread(tfunc, f, std::ref(x));`, it just works.  This is precisely the sort of situation `std::ref` exists for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when `std::thread(tfunc, f, x)` is called, x is being copied and the reference to the temporary value is passed into the functor, thus the call to the functor will not change the value of x. I think in general STL algorithms / functions always copy arguments. If you want your functor call to change the x, you may consider using pointer, as even a pointer is copied, the copy still points to the same address.